# Conversion from .NET framework 4.6 to 4.8 causing runtime error

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I have converted my web api framework target from 4.6.2 --> 4.8, this is the error I get after I change target framework and reinstall nuget packages:-

The type initializer for '**System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration**' threw an exception.. error ASPRUNTIME.

My web config have information of old library and new as below:-

```
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Can anyone suggest what is problem here. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

install Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.7 nuget package and try to run the app.

If this does not work, try commenting on this line.